# Ruby on Rails 7.0 SyntaxError: Invalid character when attempting to load assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

When I attempt to use a tag to import a file from assets, whether it be through image_tag, stylesheet_link_tag or javascript_include_tag, I get "SyntaxError: Invalid character", which points to a section that's not in my code:

```rb
begin
  extract_result(@runtime.exec_runtime(filepath), filepath)
ensure
  File.unlink(tmpfile)
end
```

New and old files have the same problem.

The file I'm using is "logo.png", and I'm using this line to use it:

```rb
<%= image_tag('logo', { id: 'standardized-image', draggable: false }) %>
```

Full trace:

```
execjs (2.8.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
execjs (2.8.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:14:in `initialize'
execjs (2.8.1) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:72:in `new'
execjs (2.8.1) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:72:in `compile'
execjs (2.8.1) lib/execjs/module.rb:27:in `compile'
babel-transpiler (0.7.0) lib/babel/transpiler.rb:24:in `context'
babel-transpiler (0.7.0) lib/babel/transpiler.rb:28:in `transform'
react-rails (2.6.2) lib/react/jsx/babel_transformer.rb:18:in `transform'
react-rails (2.6.2) lib/react/jsx.rb:24:in `transform'
react-rails (2.6.2) lib/react/jsx/processor.rb:6:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:175:in `dfs'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
sprockets (4.2.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `block in synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
```

Tried to remove the lines where assets were being imported. It worked as it should.

Comment: can you please add the complete stacktrace and maybe the filename of your asset

Comment: Added both to the OP

Comment: that error has nothing to do with your logo.png asset, you probably have some error in your javascript assets. run the assets precompile task and see if it shows a better error.

Comment: I have the same issue. A simple, humble PNG image added as an asset in a template.rb yields this message:

Comment: create    app/assets/images/logo.png
/Users/ricc/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-4.0.2/lib/erb.rb:429:in `eval': /Users/ricc/git/gprojects/rails/templates/drifting-riccardo/template/images/puffin-alchimista-small.png:574: Invalid char `\\x15' in expression (SyntaxError)
 from /Users/ricc/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-4.0.2/lib/erb.rb:429:in `result'

Comment: Marian > I disagree. Error disappears if I convert to JPG. Still is there if I convert to smaller PNG. I believe its a bug in Thor.